# writing a message to a RemoteSession VMWare

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I would like to write a message to a client who is connected via a remoteSession. I would like to use the Powershell Snap-In View PowerCli.

Is there a possibility?

My main target is: When I send a session logOff my Client should be informed in form of a pop up message that he will loged off after 5minutes or something like that.

The best solution would be to send a message automatically if I Send a SessionLogOff via PowerCli. But I found out that doesn't work with the Version 4.6.

So I want to do that manually with my own script.

Comment: Is it about a "Remote session" to a machine like remote desktop connection (mstsc) ? 
How do you do it with 4.6 ? Paste your code please.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

start-process "cmd.exe" "/c C:\msg.bat"

.bat contents would be

msg.exe /SERVER:fullcomputername theirusername HelloWorld

If you don't know the username you can use query session /server:fullcomputername and process the usernames you get back.